# Waking up a hanging process using KeyboardInterrupt python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using a library that sometimes falls inside an infinite loop. All actions inside this library are logged and i use a thread to detect when a call goes inside an infinite loop using the library logs. After detecting the loop, i need to send a signal such as `KeyboardInterrupt` to the hanging process to terminate current call and clear things up and then redo the job. Here is the code i have tried:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
def worker():
    job_not_done = True
    while job_not_done:
        try:
            call_a_library_function_that_may_fall_in_infinite_loop()
            job_not_done = False
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            do_some_clean_up()
            print('Job interrupted, restarting ...')

def watcher(process):
    infinite_loop = False
    while not infinite_loop:
        infinite_loop = detect_from_logs_if_inside_infinite_loop()
    # send keyboardInterrupt signal to process
    # process.sendSignal(KeyboardInterrupt) ??

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=starter)
p.start()
t = threading.Thread(target=watcher, args=(p,))
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
p.join()
```

I searched around but couldn't find how to send desired signals to child process. Simply calling `process.terminate()` will kill it and clearly is not what i'm looking for. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix based systems, the `SIGINT` signal is used to indicate that.  Signals are send with `kill(2)`, which is exposed in Python as `os.kill`, with signal numbers in the `signal` package.

Your use would look something like:

```
from os import kill
from signal import SIGINT

kill(process.pid, SIGINT)
```

Comment: sorry, don't use windows…  you might be better off moving the restart code into the watcher, i.e. join with a timeout and kill off if it doesn't complete

Comment: Ah, Windows makes everything complicated when programming :)